# alternative to finfo() for php < 5.3

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$finfo = new finfo();
$fileinfo = $finfo->file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], FILEINFO_MIME);

switch($fileinfo) {
    case "image/gif":
    case "image/jpeg":
    case "image/png":
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    echo "Your file has successfully been uploaded, and is awaiting moderator approval for points." . "<html><br><a href='uploadfile.php'>Upload more.</a>";
    break;
     default:
     echo "Files must be either JPEG, GIF, or PNG and less than 10,000 kb";

        break;
        }


?>
```

it has recently been brought to my attention there is nothing wrong here, it just doesnt work because my servers php is only at 5.2  lemme know if you guys can find a way to make it work using MIME

Answer (score 5):

`pecl install fileinfo`?

http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo

Comment: i dont have my own server.  is there anyway to include the function within an older version of php

Answer (score 1):

On Linux servers you can be lazy and use:

```
 $type = exec("file -iL " . escapeshellcmd($fn) . " 2>/dev/null");
 $type = trim(strtok(substr(strrchr($type, ":"), 1), ";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`mime_content_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) might still work for you.  While it's now under the `fileinfo` section in the manual, it existed *way* before `fileinfo` was brought into the PHP core.

Do note that it might require a bit of configuration if your host moved Apache's `mime.types` file out of the normal location, as documented in the comments on that page.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I know this does not directly answer the question regarding the PHP version. However, I found this post while trying to solve my issue, and so it may be helpful for someone in the future.*

I too have been struggling with the `Fileinfo` library recently while trying to validate MP3 files. I've come to understand that there are some [known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754713/why-some-mp3s-on-mime-content-type-return-application-octet-stream) [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060421/is-the-mime-type-detection-the-best-way-to-detect-a-kind-of-file) with `Fileinfo` and MP3 files, even if you've properly set the magic database file for your environment.

If `Fileinfo` cannot determine the mime type of an MP3, it may return `application/octet-stream` instead. Not very helpful when trying to validate a file.

As an alternative, I've started using the following system command. This is very similar to @mario’s suggestion, and *so far* seems more reliable than `Fileinfo`.

```
$path = 'path/to/your/mp3/file.mp3';
$mime = exec('file -b --mime-type ' . $path);
```

I've tested this on Ubuntu 10.04 and OSX Mountain Lion, so I'm guessing it works on most Unix environments. I believe there are some Windows ports as well.

Truth be told I'm not entirely sure how safe or reliable this method is, but I've seen it recommended [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398488/alternative-to-finfo-for-php-5-3#answer-5398561) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880678/mime-type-detection-fails-with-fileinfo-on-php-5-3-8#answer-7880754) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376501/severe-fileinfo-issues#answer-10376666) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227182/how-can-i-find-out-a-files-mime-typecontent-type#answer-2227201) on Stackoverflow. If anyone has any more information, please do share!