# Mime type detection fails with fileinfo on PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, centos, fileinfo

I'm having trouble detecting the mime type of a simple PNG file with fileinfo, with PHP 5.3.8 installed on a CentOS server.

**The problem**

Basically, if I have the following code :

```
<?php
$const = defined('FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE') ? FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE : FILEINFO_MIME;
$handle = finfo_open($const, '/usr/share/file/magic.mime');
$result = finfo_file($handle, '/var/vhosts/v4dev/public/Melvin.png');
echo $result;
unset($handle);
?>
```

As you can see the file is a PNG image. The header bytes of the file has been checked and are correct. But this page outputs an incorrect result :

```
application/octet-stream
```

I guess this is because the file type could not be detected, and fileinfo returned the default response, but I found no way to check that.

**What I tried**

To check the magic.mime file correctness, I used the file console command :

```
file -m /usr/share/file/magic.mime /var/vhosts/v4dev/public/Melvin.png
```

Which returned the expected result :

```
/var/vhosts/v4dev/public/Melvin.png: image/png
```

I also tried another magic.mime file provided with Apache, but the problem remains.

I tried specifying the magic.mime file through the default fileinfo location (with symlink and copy of the file), with the `MAGIC` environment variable, and by specifying the file path in the `finfo_open` call (as above).

I tried updating PHP.

... and now i'm out of options.

---

If anyone could help me with this, i'd send waves of happiness through space so he/her can live happily ever after.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

So why not call the `file` command from your script?

```
$result = `file -bm /usr/share/file/magic.mime /var/vhosts/v4dev/public/Melvin.png`
```

Sure, it's not perfect, but it's an option.

Comment: Hmm yeah that might work as a temporary hack until I got something more solid. Thanks.