# Which mime type should I use for mp3

Tags: php, mp3, mime-types

I'm trying to decide which mime type to choose for returning mp3 data (served up by php)

according to this listing of mime types: http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

```
.mp3    audio/mpeg3
.mp3    audio/x-mpeg-3
.mp3    video/mpeg
.mp3    video/x-mpeg
```

What are the difference between these, and which should I use?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Your best bet would be using the [RFC defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003) mime-type `audio/mpeg`.

Comment: Chrome 26 knows better and uses `audio/mp3`... Go figure.

Comment: Here is the [Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227004), he just turned 3 today. I'm sure he's going to stick around for a few more years, so smile and wish him a happy birthday. :)

Comment: @pollaris There is no such thing as multiple mime types, because a file is only of one type. Ideally, you would return `audio/mpeg` if you are returning an mp3 file or `audio/wav` if you are returning a wav file.  You could use the generic `application/octet-stream` to indicate a binary file if you didn't want to code for returning the actual mime type, but then the browser might not treat the file the way you expect.

Comment: @jgillich - you were right. 6 years and can now ride a bicycle

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227004

Comment: The Chrome bug has been fixed! Not sure when it'll make it into Chrome.

Answer (score 40):

I had a problem with mime types and where making tests for few file types. It looks like each browser sends it's variation of a mime type for a specific file. I was trying to upload mp3 and zip files with open source php class, that what I have found:

- Firefox (mp3): audio/mpeg
- Firefox (zip): application/zip
- Chrome  (mp3): audio/mp3
- Chrome  (zip): application/octet-stream
- Opera   (mp3): audio/mp3
- Opera   (zip): application/octet-stream
- IE      (mp3): audio/mpeg
- IE      (zip): application/x-zip-compressed

So if you need several file types to upload, you better make some tests so that every browser could upload a file and pass mime type check.

Answer (score 14):

Use `.mp3 audio/mpeg`, that's the one I always used. I guess others are just aliases.

Answer (score 6):

You should always use **audio/mpeg**, because firefox cannot play **audio/mpeg3** files

Comment: Firefox doesn't like audio/mp3 either

Answer (score 5):

The [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003) way is to use `audio/mpeg` which is something like this in your PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function ...

`header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');`

Answer (score 0):

mp3 files sometimes throw strange mime types as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2755288/14482130

If you are doing some user validation do not allow 'application/octet-stream' or 'application/x-zip-compressed' as suggested above since they can contain be .exe or other potentially dangerous files.

In order to validate when mime type gives a false negative you can use fleep as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570299/14482130
to finish the validation.