# with MediaElement.js how to streaming mp3

Tags: javascript, php, streaming, mp3, mediaelement.js

I am trying to read a mp3 stream on iOS. This is my code :

{`<audio id="player2" src="http://karaibe.info/medias/streaming_list.php?idlist=musicfond" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>`}

and the javascript script is :

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();
```

On **FireFox** it is working very well, but Safari, Chrome, IE nothing ! and no error. On my iPad, Safari refresh the page because there is an error ! of course I had loaded jquery first !
I beleive the stream is "correct" because Firefox is reading it ! I made it with php, the header is

```
header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
```

Could somebody help me ! please !
Thank you !

Comment: use "audio/mpeg", the correct MIME for MP3 files. firefox is forgiving...

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10688641/1055987

Comment: thanks !
But I have tried this already. Maybe I have to check my streaming even if i thouhgt that, since you read the all file that should be fine !