# How to make a short beep in javascript that can be called *repeatedly* on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, object, audio

This is like the question at:
[Sound effects in JavaScript / HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933969/sound-effects-in-javascript-html5/1934325#1934325)
but I'm just seeking a specific answer to the issue of repeatability.

The above question and other similar ones have helpful answers to use the following javascript:

```
function beep1()
{ var snd = new Audio("file.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
  snd.play();
}
```

or even more self-contained, you can now include a wav in-line, such as:

```
function beep2()
{ var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");  
  snd.play();
}
```

When I tried these examples, I could only get the sound to play once on my computer.  I noticed this was a common complaint in multiple questions, but never saw an answer to it.

The closest thing to an answer was in the referenced question in which @Kornel stated:

> To play same sound multiple times, create multiple instances of the Audio object.
>   You could also set snd.currentTime=0 on the object after it finishes playing.

If this is the key to my puzzle, I don't quite understand it.  (I don't know how to destroy / release an audio object.)  Can someone show me exactly how to get a button to keep replaying my sound every time it is clicked, either using one of the suggestions of @Kornel or some other way?

Comment: reuse the tag and call play() on it: http://pagedemos.com/6pz8wtgss788/2

Comment: **Note** for every-one where this base64 data url does not work: a MS 'wav' file is a MS audio container (not exclusive to PCM, so can also contain mp3) in the MS 'RIFF' format. `RIF` in Base64 = `UklG` so this is clearly **not a wav file, but an MP3 file**, so the [mime-type should probably be `audio/mpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10688588/588079) .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the sound references outside of the function. Otherwise, each time you call the function, a new sound object is created.

```js
var snd1 = new Audio("file.mp3");
var snd2 = new Audio("data:audio/mpeg;base64,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");  

function beep1() {
  snd1.play();
}

function beep2() { 
  snd2.play();
}

beep1();
setInterval(beep2, 300);
```

Comment: Your answer is working, thanks! 
... I have some remaining confusion.  Some hard-to-reproduce behaviors.  Perhaps there are issues with a process actually getting control of the speaker.  And I still don't understand why it is wrong to keep creating a new sound object.  Wasteful of resources, perhaps, but I mistakenly thought this would ensure it played again, whereas the opposite seems true.

Comment: Each time you create a new Audio, it takes a considerable amount of time to load, decode and store in memory -- so playback won't be instantaneous. However, once an Audio has been loaded and parsed, it remains in memory and is instantly accessible. Since the Audio resides in memory, you can request to play it back multiple times without any delay because each request to play simply starts reading the data from memory.

Comment: **Note** for every-one where this snippet does not work (apart from the obvious non-existing `file.wav`): a MS 'wav' file is a MS audio container (not exclusive to pcm, so can also contain mp3) in the MS 'RIFF' format. `RIF` in Base64 = `UklG` so this is clearly *not* a wav file, but an MP3 file, so the [mime-type should probably be `audio/mpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10688588/588079) .

Comment: @GitaarLAB. Good point, these issues could also affect playback as some browsers don't support WAV. I've adjusted the code accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

We can [create audio waveforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createOscillator) with the [web audio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

The following example shows a bip, made of two tones, one is at **233hz** for ***100ms*** with a gain of **10DB**, the second is at **603Hz** with a duration of ***200ms***, with **3DB** of gain.

Both sounds are in a loop of ***1500ms***, with the help of setInterval.

This is a minimal example, it can't be stopped! (As asked!)

```js
// gain, frequency, duration
let a = new AudioContext()
function k(w,x,y){
 console.log("Gain:"+w, "Hz:"+x, "ms:"+y)
  v = a.createOscillator()
  u = a.createGain()
  v.connect(u)
  v.frequency.value = x
  v.type = "square"
  u.connect(a.destination)
  u.gain.value = w * 0.01
  v.start(a.currentTime)
  v.stop(a.currentTime + y *0.001)
}

setInterval(function(){ k(10,233,100); k(3,603,200)}, 1500)
```

There is ways to create much more complex *8bits songs* in few lines, with differents loops of many duration and tones:

```js
let a = new AudioContext()
function k(w,x,y){
 console.log("Gain:"+w, "Hz:"+x, "ms:"+y)
  let v = a.createOscillator()
  let u = a.createGain()
  v.connect(u)
  v.frequency.value = x
  v.type = "square"
  u.connect(a.destination)
  u.gain.value = w * 0.01
  v.start(a.currentTime)
  v.stop(a.currentTime + y *0.001)
}
setInterval(function(){ k(10,233,100); k(3,603,200)}, 1000)
setInterval(function(){ k(8,1646,100); k(8,1444,100) }, 500)
setInterval(function(){ k(8,728,100); k(8,728,100) }, 3000)
setInterval(function(){ k(8,728,100); k(8,728,100) }, 3000)
setInterval(function(){ k(8,364,100); k(8,364,100) }, 6000)
setInterval(function(){ k(8,364,100); k(8,157,200) }, 12000)
```

We can as well set the values in an array, and loop trough it.

With `for, for..in, while, do..while`, much more complex, but to create **patterns**, arpeggios, etc.

Someone, one day will enjoy this ;)

Answer (score 3):

What about using the new Audio API. (No Microsoft support!)

```
var audioContext = AudioContext && new AudioContext();
function beep(amp, freq, ms){//amp:0..100, freq in Hz, ms
  if (!audioContext) return;
  var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
  var gain = audioContext.createGain();
  osc.connect(gain);
  osc.value = freq;
  gain.connect(audioContext.destination);
  gain.gain.value = amp/100;
  osc.start(audioContext.currentTime);
  osc.stop(audioContext.currentTime+ms/1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_loop.asp)
Just the HTML5 thing

```
 <audio controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: I do not want my sound to continuously replay, but to be replayed at intervals controlled by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an "alert" for a web app that will be used predominately on a mobile device. The new autoplay policy https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes, was giving me a problem so I did this...
Top of html code to play the "alert" you need a button so the user interacts with the page and authorizes future use of audio.

```
<p align="center" id="snd_btn"><button id="allow_alert" class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="play_sound();"> Allow Alert </button></p>
```

Add'l html...................

then later in the script section I have ....

```
<script>
function play_sound(){
    snd.play(); // plays the "1-second-of-silence.mp3"
    $("#snd_btn").hide(); // this hides the prompt "Allow Alert"
}

snd = new Audio("sound/1-second-of-silence.mp3"); 
snd2 = new Audio("sound/PHONERNG.WAV");
```

the as part of an online event (map coordinates update) this is included in the ajax success function ...

```
success: function(data){
        if(data['badge'] > 0){
        $("#vt_badge").html(data['badge']);
        snd2.play(); //Plays the  "alert" sound
        } 
    }

'''''
</script>
```

Th "allow alert" button is only there on page load so the user interacts with it, and it plays a sound, "1-second-of-silence.mp3". That satisfies the player's requirement for page interaction, now the actual alert, "PHONERNG.WAV" plays automatically as required.
MrFitz

Answer (score 0):

This works better for me.
Just follow the snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Press the Button</h1>

    <button onclick="play()">Press Here!</button>

    <script>
        function play() {
            var audio = new Audio(
'https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190531135120/beep.mp3');
            audio.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).