# how to Add current file to "delete list" except file with mp3 and mp4 extension?

Tags: php, php-5.3

i want to make delete-list but except mp3 and mp4 file

my code is

error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function endsWith() in E:\xampp\htdocs\tes\index.php on line 39

```
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        $zip->close();

        // Add current file to "delete list"
        // delete it later cause ZipArchive create archive only after calling close function and ZipArchive lock files until archive created)
        if ($file->getFilename().endsWith(".mp3")) error at this code
        {
            $filesToDelete[] = $filePath;
        }
    }
}
```

anyone help me please

Comment: check the mime-type of the file, file-extensions (e.g. .mp3) are unreliable

Comment: its cannot solve

Comment: I notice you've specified the `php-5.3` tag. Please be aware that this php version is now very old and unsupported. You should be urgently considering upgrading to at least version 5.6 to avoid security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Again, checking the file-extension is unreliable. You should check the mime-type of the file with: [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

In your code, you can do something like this:

```
// Add current file to "delete list"
        // delete it later cause ZipArchive create archive only after calling close function and ZipArchive lock files until archive created)
        if (mime_content_type($filePath) == "audio/mp3"))
        {
            $filesToDelete[] = $filePath;
        }
```

But be carefull because there're a lot of different mime-types for mp3, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688588/which-mime-type-should-i-use-for-mp3).

edit:
If you wan't to check for multiple mime_types you can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php):

```
if(in_array(mime_content_type($filePath), ['audio/mp3','audio/mpeg']))
```

Comment: Even checking mime type can be unreliable and dangerous, but at least it's better than file extensions.

Comment: how to add two type?? mean audio/mp3 and video/mp4 or anymore

Answer (score 0):

The is no endsWith function. You need to create your own. Check this example.

[startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

Comment: Then what should i do?

Comment: Check the link in my comment there is example, how to implement this functionality