# How can I download audio file when meet 307 redirect

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I write a `cpp` program to download audio file throw `http`. The principal part of programe is:

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
sprintf(header, \
        "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"\
        "Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\n"\
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526Safari/537.36\r\n"\
        "Host: %s\r\n"\
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"\
        "\r\n"\
    ,resource_relative_url.c_str(), host); 
write(client_socket, header, strlen(header));
...
Get And Print The Return Header of First Request
...
if(resp.status_code ==302 || resp.status_code ==307)
{
     sprintf(header, \
     "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"\
     "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\n"\
     "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526Safari/537.36\r\n"\
     "Host: %s\r\n"\
     "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"\
     "\r\n"\
     ,resp.szLocation, host);
     write(client_socket, header, strlen(header));
     ...
     Get And Print The Return Header of Second Request
     ...
read(client_socket, buf, buf_len);
...
```

It works correctly and download audio file most of the time, but it only download a html web file when meets `307` redirect.
Such as this url `http://ip:port/fe-see/monday.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=hhaminio%2F20210220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210220T071210Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f051bd64f5617525fa03dc9df275f6bfc7eb477626009dc4a62484d197c16b2e`,

This is a correct url, I can download audio file throw google browser. But use my program get `307` redirect at first request. I get the return header as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Location: /minio/fe-see/monday.mp3
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 1665C27CE2C0AE10
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2021 12:18:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I get the return header at second time is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 2281
Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 23:01:55 GMT
Vary: Origin
X-Amz-Request-Id: 1665C25BF3FBDA93
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2021 12:15:41 GMT
```

The return code is `200`, but the file is not an audio file, it is a `html` file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MinIO Browser</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/minio/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/minio/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/minio/favicon-16x16.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/minio/loader.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-load">
        <div class="pl-inner">
            <img src="/minio/logo.svg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!--[if lt IE 11]>
        <div class="ie-warning">
            <div class="iw-inner">
                <i class="iwi-icon fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>

                You are using Internet Explorer version 12.0 or lower. Due to security issues and lack of support for Web Standards it is highly recommended that you upgrade to a modern browser

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">
                            <img src="chrome.png" alt="">
                            <div>Chrome</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">
                            <img src="firefox.png" alt="">
                            <div>Firefox</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.apple.com/safari/">
                            <img src="safari.png" alt="">
                            <div>Safari</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div class="iwi-skip">Skip & Continue</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>currentUiVersion = '2019-10-09T23:01:31Z'</script>
    <script src="/minio/index_bundle-2019-10-09T23-01-31Z.js"> 
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am so confused, how can I handle the redirection to get the audio file? Is there sth wrong in request body or request method ?

Comment: You are manifesting that you accept
"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;", maybe just adding the correct mime type would be enough
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688588/which-mime-type-should-i-use-for-mp3

Otherwise check what are the headers sent by the browser and replicate them.

Comment: @user12750353 I added the mime type and got the same result with before,  maybe not this reason as I can get audio file correctly if it is not 307 redirect.

Comment: And `resp.szLocation` is exactly what? Have you compared the value you use here with what you see in developer tools in the browser?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich In the first request `resource_relative_url` is `fe-see/monday.mp3`, the second request `resp.szLocation` is the `Location` in the return header: `/minio/fe-see/monday.mp3`, It is the real url.

Comment: @YongqiZ: *"In the first request resource_relative_url is `fe-see/monday.mp3`"* - it must be `/fe-see/....`, i.e. the path must start with a slash.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich，yes, sorry，it is `/fe-see/monday.mp3` in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved, the url is `http://ip:port/fe-see/monday.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=hhaminio%2F20210220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210220T071210Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f051bd64f5617525fa03dc9df275f6bfc7eb477626009dc4a62484d197c16b2e`,

but in the request body I filled in `/fe-see/monday.mp3`,

I change it to `/fe-see/monday.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=hhaminio%2F20210220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210220T071210Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f051bd64f5617525fa03dc9df275f6bfc7eb477626009dc4a62484d197c16b2e`, now it can download the audio file.