# Is it possible to check that mp3 file is exactly mp3 file with php?

Tags: php, mp3, id3

When checking mime type, php sometimes fails to detect mimetype, and giving back "application/octet-stream".

I've tried to check if getid3 php library could do this - but i can't understand to which data/option i can bind, audio data format parameter is also sometimes missing. Is it possible to perform correct check that file is mp3?

Answer given by @gordon is not appropriate(my question was marked as duplicate): [PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006632/php-how-can-i-check-if-a-file-is-mp3-or-image-file)
Because, as i wrote, wrong mime type is detected. @gordon, please read questions carefully before marking them duplicate.

Comment: Answer given as "duplicate" is not appropriate(my question was marked as duplicate): PHP how can i check if a file is mp3 or image file? Because, as i wrote, wrong mime type is detected. @gordon, please read questions carefully before marking them duplicate.

Comment: There is multiple answers and solutions in the given dupe. Not just mine. Did you try all of them? Did they all fail? Also, did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754713/why-some-mp3s-on-mime-content-type-return-application-octet-stream already? If so, update your question to include your research and failed attempts.